# Laravel:: How to attach a Request instance to redirect?

Tags: laravel, controller

I have a controller function that accepts Request instant from form through a get method, I want to redirect to this route from the controller and attach a Request to it.

**Route**

```
Route::get('/{order_id}/return-calc', 'returnCalc')->name('return-calc');
```

**Controller**

```
public function return(Request $request, $order_id)
{
    $order = Order::with([
        'products' => fn ($q) => $q->with('thumbnail')
    ])->findOrFail($order_id);

    if ($request->method() == 'GET') {
        return view('front.orders.return_products', compact('order'));
    } elseif ($request->method() == 'DELETE') {
        $request = new Request([
            'products_ids' => $order->products->pluck('id')->toArray(),
            'quantities' => $order->products->pluck('pivot.quantity')->toArray(),
        ]);

        return redirect()->route('front.orders.return-calc', [$order_id, $request]);
    }
}
```

Comment: a redirect will cause a new request to be made. You can't pass the old request instance as a parameter, you should use `->with` to [flash some data](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/redirects#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data) but you should only flash the data that needs to be passed on, you can't pass the entire current request as it contains things that can't be serialized to the session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `with` to send data:

```
return redirect()->route('front.orders.return-calc')->with(['order_id' => $order_id, 'request' => $request]);
```

and then for reading, you can use session:

```
$order_id = Session::get('order_id');
$request  = Session::get('request');
```

or

```
$order_id = session()->get('order_id');
$request  = session()->get('request');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need a request instance in your blade file, you can directly use `request()` or `Request` class. But if you need data like `products_ids`, `quantities` you can pass it like this:

```
public function return(Request $request, $order_id)
{
    $order = Order::with([
        'products' => fn ($q) => $q->with('thumbnail')
    ])->findOrFail($order_id);

    if ($request->method() == 'GET') {
        return view('front.orders.return_products', compact('order'));
    } elseif ($request->method() == 'DELETE') {
        $data = [
            'products_ids' => $order->products->pluck('id')->toArray(),
            'quantities' => $order->products->pluck('pivot.quantity')->toArray(),
        ];

        return redirect()->route('front.orders.return-calc', [ 'order_id' => $order_id])->with('data', $data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing data to the route function is for route parameters, to share data between requests you should store it in the session if it's a one time thing you can "flash" it

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/responses#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data

Add `->with()` to the response

```php
public function return(Request $request, $order_id)
    {
        $order = Order::with([
            'products' => fn ($q) => $q->with('thumbnail')
        ])->findOrFail($order_id);

        if ($request->method() == 'GET') {
            return view('front.orders.return_products', compact('order'));
        } elseif ($request->method() == 'DELETE') {
            $request = new Request([
                'products_ids' => $order->products->pluck('id')->toArray(),
                'quantities' => $order->products->pluck('pivot.quantity')->toArray(),
            ]);

            return redirect()->route('front.orders.return-calc')->with(['order_id' => $order_id]);
        }
    }
```